# Using Javascript with HTML drop-down select

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am having problems using data from a drop down list with my javascript. I want it to print out on the page based off what is selected, but so far when they select a value, nothing happens. I am new to javasript, please help:

```
<form>
    <select name="abc" id="abc" onChange="check(this.form)">
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script>
    function check (form){
        var letter = document.getElementsById("abc");
        var userLtr = letter.options[letter.selectedIndex].value;
        if (userLtr == "a"){
            document.write ("You selected A");
        }
        else if(userLtr == "b"){
            document.write ("You selected B");
        }
        else{
            document.write ("You selected C");
        }
    }
</script>
```

edit: Thank you all for the help. I have figured it out!!

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementId`. You also need some sort of event handler like onchange

Answer (score 2):

Your code in the `<script>` section is only execute when the page is ready. You'd need to use something like `onchange` on the select tag and a function to handle it. [onchange event.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) And the `getDocumentId` should be `getDocumentById`, you can [check out the docs on that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

```
<select name="abc" id="abc" onchange="handleChange()">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
<script>
    function handleChange() {
      var letter = document.getElementById("abc");
      var userLtr = letter.options[letter.selectedIndex].value;
      if(userLtr == "a"){
         document.write("You selected A");
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Keep in mind though, that using `document.write()` will remove all of your existing HTML (the `select` and options) and replace it with what you have provided, 'You selected A'. You can [read more about the `write` function here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do that:

```
        <select name="abc" id="abc">
            <option value="a">A</option>
            <option value="b">B</option>
            <option value="c">C</option>
        </select>

        <div id="text"></div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("abc").onchange = function () {
                if (this.value === "a")
                {
                    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "You selected A!";
                }
            };
        </script>
```

Comment: Nice touch changing the destructive document.write to use innerHTML instead

Comment: @th1nkful Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend using innerText instead of innerHTML as this is a safer alternative. You can see my question where I did something similar to this.

Comment: @Daniel True, but in this case I don't think it makes a huge difference.

Comment: I just wanted to point it out because the OP is "new to javascript" and probably hasn't thought of XSS attacks at all yet.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "by" in "getElementById".

If you add an onchange event listener that is linked to the javascript function that will write into a div, you can then use a template string to show which option is selected as can be seen below.

```js
function changedFunc() {
  var letter = document.getElementById("abc");
  var userLtr = letter.options[letter.selectedIndex].value;
  document.querySelector('#write-target').innerText =`You selected ${userLtr}`;
} 
changedFunc();
```

```html
<select name="abc" id="abc" onchange="changedFunc()">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
<div id="write-target"></div>
```

Comment: This still won't work as the code will only be executed when the page loads. He would need to an event handler too

Comment: Didn't spot that before I added my comment, whoops!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the typo on `getElementById` you should add an event listener to the select element:

```
<script>
    var letter = document.getElementById("abc");
    letter.addEventListener('change', handleSelect) 
    function handleSelect(e) {
        var userLtr = letter.options[letter.selectedIndex].value;
        if(userLtr == "a"){
            document.write("You selected A");
        }
    }   
</script>
```